# Golang how to convert string slice to string?

Tags: go

Here's the error:

```
ubuntu@buildserver:~/gospace$ go build src/runk/test.go
# command-line-arguments
src/runk/test.go:8: cannot convert myvar (type []string) to type string
ubuntu@buildserver:~/gospace$
```

Here's the code:

```
ubuntu@buildserver:~/gospace$ cat src/run/test.go
package main

func Test() string {

    var myvar []string
    myvar = append(myvar, "hello world")

    return string(myvar)

}

func main() {
    Test()
}
ubuntu@buildserver:~/gospace$
```

Comment: @Amit I don't understand what you are asking.  Why would I want to do a one line return hello world? That makes no sense.

Answer (score 4):

`myvar` is a slice of strings, and you want a single string? If you just want to concatinate them you can use `strings.Join(myvar,"")`.

Or not make a string slice in the first place:

```
myvar := ""
myvar += "hello, world!"
return myvar
```